# Filter array returning arguments

Tags: python, filter, arguments, scipy

here we go again:

I would like a function much like *filter*, but it ought to return *arguments* rather than values:

```
data = numpy.array([0.0, 35., 2., 44., numpy.pi, numpy.sqrt(2.)])
args_pass_A = some_sort_of_f(lambda x: x<4., data)
print(args_pass_A)
[0, 2, 4, 5]
args_pass_B = some_sort_of_f(lambda x: x>=44., data)
print(args_pass_B)
[3]
```

I tried to lookup in scipy.stats and scipy.stats.mstats, where I've been recently directed towards *mquantiles* (thank you aganders3). Does this ring any bell? I also tried to lookup in numpy documentation, but with no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case I'd just use `where` [[docs]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> data = numpy.array([0.0, 35., 2., 44., numpy.pi, numpy.sqrt(2.)])
>>> data
array([  0.        ,  35.        ,   2.        ,  44.        ,
         3.14159265,   1.41421356])
>>> numpy.where(data < 4)
(array([0, 2, 4, 5]),)
>>> numpy.where(data > 44.)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
>>> numpy.where(data >= 44.)
(array([3]),)
```

Note that what you're looking for is really the first element of the returned tuple:

```
>>> numpy.where(data < 4)[0]
array([0, 2, 4, 5])
```

and you can use these indices to index `data` again:

```
>>> data[numpy.where(data < 4)[0]]
array([ 0.        ,  2.        ,  3.14159265,  1.41421356])
```

Comment: Yes, this answers my question! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` function, which accepts a list (`orig_list`) and return list of pairs, in which first element is index of item in `orig_list` and second element - that item from `orig_list`.

Example:

```
orig_list = numpy.array([0.0, 35., 2., 44., numpy.pi, numpy.sqrt(2.)])
filter_func = lambda (idx, value): value<4.
filtered_pairs = filter(filter_func, enumerate(orig_list))
result = map(lambda (idx, value): idx, filtered_pairs)
```

You also can replace id extractor with stdlib function `itemgetter` (module operator):

```
from operator import itemgetter
orig_list = numpy.array([0.0, 35., 2., 44., numpy.pi, numpy.sqrt(2.)])
filter_func = lambda (idx, value): value<4.
result = map(itemgetter(0), filter(filter_func, enumerate(orig_list)))
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Even though I find the one above quicker, this one really helped me revealing the existence of *itemgetter* and *enumerate*. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def some_sort_of_f(data, condition = lambda x: x<4.):
        rez=[]
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if condition(data[i]):
                rez.append(i)
        return rez

>>> data = [0.0, 35., 2., 44.]
>>> some_sort_of_f(data)
[0, 2]
>>>
```